# Getting max date in Jinja template

Tags: jquery, max, jinja2

I have the following template:

```
{% block begin_content scoped %}
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
{% endblock %}
{% block begin_loop_values %}
    {% if actions %}
        <th>Diagnosis</th>
        <th>MRN</th>
        <th>Max Dx Date</th>

    {% endif %}
    {% for item in value_columns %}

        {% for dx in value_columns | groupby('dx_code') %}
            {% for person in group.list | groupby('mrn') %}
                <div class="table-responsive">

                    <td>{{ dx.grouper }}</td>
                    <td>{{ person.grouper }}</td>

               </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}


    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

{% block end_content scoped %}
</table>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Where I am grouping data that look like:

```
{'dx_code': u'1234', 'mrn': u'12345678', 'dx_date': u'1/28/2015'}

{'dx_code': u'1234', 'mrn': u'12345678', 'dx_date': u'1/28/2014'}

{'dx_code': u'1234', 'mrn': u'12345678', 'dx_date': u'1/28/2013'}

{'dx_code': u'1234', 'mrn': u'12345678', 'dx_date': u'1/28/2012'}

{'dx_code': u'1234', 'mrn': u'12345678', 'dx_date': u'1/28/2011'}
```

That works great, but now I need to get the MAX `dx_date` somehow and print it with the grouped data in my template. I am assuming I need to insert a jQuery function to do this - something like

```
<script language="javascript">
    var latest = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, dx.dx_date));
</script>
```

, but am not sure how to get it's value into my template?

Comment: Could you calculate the max date server-side and pass that variable into your template?

Comment: Yes, but it would take a lot of work to change the endpoint. Worst case, I could make my table an SQL view and get it from there via a GROUP BY, but that feels dirty and just plain wrong!